# What is the purpose of View>Page Style in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

What is the purpose of this menu? Are there supposed to be more options than `no style` and `basic page style`? Can I add more Styles? Does this have a history?

[image: menu]
[image: view]
[image: page style]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the website that provides the stylesheets. Some websites provide a choice of stylesheets which can be toggled between using this menu. [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets) which gives the following example:

```
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Default Style">
<link href="fancy.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Fancy">
<link href="basic.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Basic">
```